# Extract date from log file

Tags: bash, date, awk, grep

I have a log line like this:

```
Tue Dec  2 10:03:46 2014 1 10.0.0.1 0 /home/test4/TEST_LOGIN_201312021003.201412021003.23872.sqlLdr b _ i r test4 ftp 0 * c
```

And I can print date value of this line like this.

```
echo $log | awk '{print $9}' | grep -oP '(?<!\d)201\d{9}' | head -n 1
```

I have another log line like this, how can I print date value?

```
Tue Dec  9 10:48:13 2014 1 10.0.0.1 80 /home/DATA1/2014/12/11/16/20/blablabla_data-2014_12_11_16_20.txt b _ i r spy ftp 0 * c
```

I tried my awk/grep solution, but it prints `201` and `9` number after `201` when see `201`.

Sub folders and data name is the same:

```
2014/12/11/16/20 --> 11 Dec 2014 16:20 <-- blablabla_data-2014_12_11_16_20.txt
```

note: `/home/DATA1` is not static. `year/month/day/hour/minute` is static.

Comment: if it is not static, provide the pattern it follows. Is it always two directories or can be more? Also, in your first code, `awk` pipe could be removed because you end up using a `grep`

Comment: To be clear, you want to match either this format `201312021003` or this `2014/12/11/16/20`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the format in the path is `/.../YYYY/MM/DD/HH/MM/filename`, you can use `201D/DD/DD/DD/DD` in the `grep` expression to match the date block:

```
$ log="Tue Dec  9 10:48:13 2014 1 10.0.0.1 80 /home/DATA1/2014/12/11/16/20/blablabla_data2_11_16_20.txt b _ i r spy ftp 0 * c"
$ echo "$log" | grep -oP '(?<!\d)201\d/\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}'
2014/12/11/16/20
```

And eventually remove the slashes with `tr`:

```
$ echo "$log" | grep -oP '(?<!\d)201\d/\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}' | tr -d '/'
201412111620
```

Answer (score 1):

sed can also work too, if you are acquainted with it

```
echo "Tue Dec  9 10:48:13 2014 1 10.0.0.1 80 /home/DATA1/2014/12/11/16/20/blablabla_data-2014_12_11_16_20.txt b _ i r spy ftp 0 * c"|sed  's#.*[[:alnum:]]*/\([[:digit:]]\{4\}/[[:digit:]]\{2\}/[[:digit:]]\{2\}/[[:digit:]]\{2\}/[[:digit:]]\{2\}\).*#\1#'
```

output

```
2014/12/11/16/20
```

To remove "/", the same above command piped to `tr -d '/'`

Full command line

```
echo "Tue Dec  9 10:48:13 2014 1 10.0.0.1 80 /home/DATA1/2014/12/11/16/20/blablabla_data-2014_12_11_16_20.txt b _ i r spy ftp 0 * c"|sed  's#.*[[:alnum:]]*/\([[:digit:]]\{4\}/[[:digit:]]\{2\}/[[:digit:]]\{2\}/[[:digit:]]\{2\}/[[:digit:]]\{2\}\).*#\1#'|tr -d '/'
```

Output

```
201412111620
```