# How to split the date and time from log file?

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, grep

I want to display the date and time separated with space. The test.log file contains lots of other information as well.

```
grep -E '[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}T[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}' test.log
```

test.log

```
2016-03-02T10:23:16
2016-03-02T10:23:16
2016-03-02T10:23:16
2016-03-02T10:23:16
2016-03-02T10:23:36
2016-03-02T10:23:36
2016-03-02T10:23:36
2016-03-02T10:23:36
2016-03-02T10:23:36
2016-03-02T10:23:36
2016-03-02T10:23:36
2016-03-02T10:24:35
```

Output should be

```
2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:24:35
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F 'T' '{print $1, $2}' test.log 
2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:24:35
```

or

```
$ sed 's/T/ /' test.log 
2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:24:35
```

or

```
$ tr "T" " " < test.log 
2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:24:35
```

Edit:

Since you have fields separated by space in a single line ,take the 1st field and remove brackets to get the date and time like this:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/^[\s\[]*|[\s*\]]*$/, "", $1); print $1}' <<< "[2016-02-24T19:59:41.584+00:00] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 005B8a1_^kLDoYUO26L6hz0002S700031R,0:3] [APP: clarientloginga] [DSID: 0000LCKpi5C7y0a_lLK6yZ1MmtvP00006z] [SRC_CLASS: com.dtcc.iam.login.servlet.PostAuthnServlet] [SRC_METHOD: doGet] RETURN" | tr 'T' ' '
2016-02-24 19:59:41.584+00:00
```

Comment: and how can i extact date and time from this line [2016-02-24T19:59:41.584+00:00] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 005B8a1_^kLDoYUO26L6hz0002S700031R,0:3] [APP: clarientloginga] [DSID: 0000LCKpi5C7y0a_lLK6yZ1MmtvP00006z] [SRC_CLASS: com.dtcc.iam.login.servlet.PostAuthnServlet] [SRC_METHOD: doGet] RETURN

Comment: the output i am getting is 2016-02-24T19:59:41.584+00:00 i want the output in 2016-02-24 19:59:41.Can you please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

Simple `tr` command will do the job:

```
tr 'T' ' ' < file

2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:24:35
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut` with `T` as the input delimiter and define a space as the output delimiter:

```
$ cut -d T --output-delimiter=' ' -f 1,2 test.log
2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:16
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:23:36
2016-03-02 10:24:35
```

Comment: How can i extract date and time from this line  `[2016-02-24T19:59:41.584+00:00] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 005B8a1_^kLDoYUO26L6hz0002S700031R,0:3] [APP: clarientloginga] [DSID: 0000LCKpi5C7y0a_lLK6yZ1MmtvP00006z] [SRC_CLASS: com.dtcc.iam.login.servlet.PostAuthnServlet] [SRC_METHOD: doGet] RETURN`

Comment: @Ajinkya That should probably be a new question - which probably has already been asked by somebody else, if you search for a while. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425207/extract-date-from-log-file) looks like something useful. Or, you could try a bit on your own, as there are many possible solutions: grep with the `-o` flag, `cut` for specific characters...